# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [128,784] vs. [96,784]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I'm running VAE model with python Keras.
And I face the error when fitting the autoencoder model (it's named 'vae' here).

error:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [128,784] vs. [96,784]

But I think both shapes are identical here as I am showing below.
It's very helpful if anyone could give me some advice.thanks.

My code:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda, Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.losses import mse, binary_crossentropy
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K


original_dim = 784 #28 * 28
input_shape = (original_dim, )
intermediate_dim = 512
batch_size = 128
latent_dim = 2
epochs = 50
epsilon_std = 1.0


#encoding
x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, original_dim))
h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation = 'relu')(x) #h = hidden layer

#creating latent variable = z
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h) #mean of latent variable (2 dimension)
z_log_sigma = Dense(latent_dim)(h) #log_sigma of latent variable (2 dimension)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim),
                              mean=0., 
                              #std=epsilon_std
                              )
    return(z_mean + K.exp(z_log_sigma) * epsilon)

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape = (latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma])

#encoder
encoder = Model(x, z_mean)

#decoding with z
decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')
decoder_mean = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')

h_decoded = decoder_h(z)#input encoded z
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)

#autoencoder
vae = Model(x, x_decoded_mean)

#decoding to generate images
decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
_h_decoded = decoder_h(decoder_input)
_x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(_h_decoded)

#generator
generator = Model(decoder_input, _x_decoded_mean)


#training
def vae_loss(x,x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = binary_crossentropy(x,x_decoded_mean)
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.mean(1+z_log_sigma-K.square(z_mean)-K.exp(z_log_sigma), axis=-1)
    return(xent_loss+kl_loss)

vae.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss=vae_loss)

#creating dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
print('x_train', x_train.shape)
print('x_test', x_test.shape)

vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

Comment: Can you give us a copy-paste of the whole error message ?

Comment: It seems you are hardcoding the batch size in your model, instead of leaving it variable. This will cause you issues with the last input batch if your data samples are not an exact multiple of the batch size (the last batch is smaller, hence the error you're seeing). Consider either ditching specifying the batch size in your model definition (leving it as `None`) or trimming your data so it's exactly a multipleof the batch size.

Comment: @GPhilo Thank for your comment. Sorry, I'm quite new and I don't really understand what you're pointing out...why don't they have the same batch size even though I settle batch size? And how exactly do I fix the code? I'm more than happy if you could show me any code sample...Thank again.

Comment: No need to be sorry, we've all been new ;)  I'll elaborate more in an a proper answer

Answer (score 4):

Given your code, it would seem you're hardcoding the batch size in the model, which is in general a bad idea.

Since you define the input as `x = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, original_dim))`, the network expects data exactly in the shape `(128, 784)`. This is problematic if you have input data that is not exactly a multiple of 128, because `vae.fit()` will split the data in batches and, for the last batch, if it doesn't have enough data to fill a full batch it will send a partial one. It seems, your last batch only has 96 samples instead of 128, so the model raises a shape mismatch error.

The correct way to do this is: Do not specify the batch size anywhere in the model and only pass the parameter to `fit`. Practically, this boils down to never use the `batch_shape` argument of Keras layers, using instead `shape` and passing in the shape of one sample:

```
x = Input(shape=(original_dim,))
```

If you have any operations that require you to specify the full shape (meaning, batch size included), use `None`:

```
epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(None, latent_dim),
                          mean=0., 
                          #std=epsilon_std
                          )
```

Comment: Thank you so much and this totally convinces me. So can I ask in what kind of case do you set batch_size for creating a model? Sorry for asking a lot of questions!

Comment: No worries :) In principle, you never set the batch size in the model unless you have a very good reason to. The batch size is a training hyper-parameter that has nothing to do with the model itself, so the model should be agnostic w.r.t. the specific batch size used during training